# How to send attribute data to the controller through ajax remote:true option in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
$.ajax {
url: 
type:
data: whatever we mention here are going to available in param hash inside controller
dataType: 
success: () ->
```

}
**But i actually want to know how to send data by using remote:true option **

```
<input type="checkbox" data-remote="true" data-url="/check" data-chatid="something" data-method="get">
```

** I want to read the data-chatid in the controller **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`data-params` attribute](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#data-url-and-data-params):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-remote="true" data-url="/check" data-params="chatid=something" data-method="get">
```

Comment: Whats the difference between that and just passing `data-chatid` as a data param in ajax using jquery?  `$(this).attr('data-chatid');` on a click event?

Comment: @Thomas that's a somewhat nonsensical question as the two things are not comparable. This augments an existing event handler while in that case you have to write a click event handler and send the ajax request and handle the response. Yeah they both do the same thing but the comparison is meaningless.